# Different handling of whitespace in span elements

Tags: svelte

Given this example [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3e21bdb5053c49bdb2406275be802dec?version=3.59.1)

```
<script>
    const arr = ['foo', ' ', 'bar']
</script>

{#each arr as a}
<span>{a}</span>
{/each}

<span>foo</span><span> </span><span>bar</span>
```

the `#each` block generates the expected output `foo bar`, but with the span elements below the whitespace is missing `foobar`. This usually shouldn't be the case?

```html
<span>foo</span><span> </span><span>bar</span>
```

Looking at the console it seems, this is not a display issue, but that it's actually not present.

[image]

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely just a bug, e.g. [this issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6381) mentions certain whitespace disappearing.

It looks like leading whitespace is trimmed; this:

```html
<i>a</i><i>  b  </i><i>c</i>
```

Results in:

```
<i>a</i><i>b  </i><i>c</i>
```

No SSR:

```js
i0 = element("i");
i0.textContent = "a";
i1 = element("i");
i1.textContent = "b  ";
i2 = element("i");
i2.textContent = "c";
```

SSR:

```js
return `<i>a</i><i>b  </i><i>c</i>`
```

---

You already found that inserting variables (in your example via `#each`) circumvents this, so a workaround would be to insert the spaces as a JS string if necessary.

```html
<i>a</i><i>{'  '}b  </i><i>c</i>
```

Comment: I've just found out that there is also a compiler option `preserveWhitespace` *If `true`, whitespace inside and between elements is kept as you typed it, rather than removed or collapsed to a single space where possible.* that might be a good to know alternative when the problem can't simply be solved with the `{' '}` workaround